# no REST endpoint working in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I am trying to start the simple `SpringBootApplication` with `REST` endpoint.
Main application looks like this

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class JudgeRuleEngineApplication {

    /**
     * Main application.
     * @param args console args
     */
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(JudgeRuleEngineApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

`REST` route definition looks like this

```
@Configuration
public class RuleExecutionRest {

    private PlayerRuleCalculationService service;

    /**
     * Constructor injection.
     * @param service calculation service
     */
    @Autowired
    public RuleExecutionRest(final PlayerRuleCalculationService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    /**
     * Increases player level if needed.
     * @return player
     */
    @Bean
    public RouterFunction<?> validatePlayer() {
        return route(POST("/judge/rest/player"),
            request -> {
                Mono<Player> player = request.bodyToMono(Player.class);
                return ServerResponse.ok().body(fromPublisher(service.levelUp(player), Player.class));
            });
    }

}
```

In `build.gradle` I specified dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
```

`application.properties` looks like this

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/judge-re-db
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

I start application with `gradlew bootRun`. But when I try access any endpoint

But it writes in logs

```
DefaultErrorWebExceptionHandler : Failed to handle request [GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/bad-request]: Response status 404
```

For request like this

```
https://localhost:8080/judge-re/judge/rest/player
{
    "id": "1",
    "level": "1",
    "experience": "1000"
}
```

And when I try to access `actuator` I get

```
2018-03-04 00:02:21.782 ERROR 6864 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : Unhandled failure: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the
 remote host, response already set (status=404)
2018-03-04 00:02:21.786 ERROR 6864 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] o.s.h.s.r.ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter      : Handling completed with error

java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.writev0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.writev(SocketDispatcher.java:55) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:148) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:504) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doWrite(NioSocketChannel.java:418) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush0(AbstractChannel.java:934) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.flush0(AbstractNioChannel.java:360) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush(AbstractChannel.java:901) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.flush(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1376) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:776) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:768) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:749) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.flush(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:533) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar
:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.flush(ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.java:115) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.flush(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:358) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:776) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:768) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:749) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelDuplexHandler.flush(ChannelDuplexHandler.java:117) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:776) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:768) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:749) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
        at reactor.ipc.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler$PublisherSender.onComplete(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:535) ~[reactor-netty-0.7.5.RELEASE.jar:0.7.5.RELE
ASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextStart$ContextStartSubscriber.onComplete(FluxContextStart.java:122) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:245) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ChannelSendOperator$WriteBarrier.onComplete(ChannelSendOperator.java:197) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEA
SE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMapFuseable.java:138) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxJust$WeakScalarSubscription.request(FluxJust.java:93) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:156) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ChannelSendOperator$WriteBarrier.onSubscribe(ChannelSendOperator.java:140) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELE
ASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:90) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxJust.subscribe(FluxJust.java:68) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable.subscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:63) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ChannelSendOperator.subscribe(ChannelSendOperator.java:74) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:150) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1069) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:241) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:198) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:1626) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxPeekFuseable.java:138) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:230) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxPeekFuseable.java:172) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:54) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekFuseable.subscribe(MonoPeekFuseable.java:74) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:150) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:67) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:67) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:1626) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:1440) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onSubscribe(Operators.java:1314) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:54) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3080) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:75) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.complete(Operators.java:125) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoEmpty.subscribe(MonoEmpty.java:45) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSwitchIfEmpty.subscribe(MonoSwitchIfEmpty.java:44) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSwitchIfEmpty.subscribe(MonoSwitchIfEmpty.java:44) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:60) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:60) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3080) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:97) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onError(FluxPeekFuseable.java:222) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onError(MonoPeekTerminal.java:270) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.secondError(MonoFlatMap.java:185) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:251) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onError(MonoPeekTerminal.java:270) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:165) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.secondError(MonoFlatMap.java:185) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:251) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.onError(Operators.java:1112) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreInner.onError(MonoIgnoreThen.java:229) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:165) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onError(Operators.java:1309) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.error(Operators.java:175) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoError.subscribe(MonoError.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3080) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:75) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onComplete(MonoFlatMap.java:174) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onComplete(MonoNext.java:96) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.drain(FluxConcatMap.java:349) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.onSubscribe(FluxConcatMap.java:210) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:128) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:61) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap.subscribe(FluxConcatMap.java:121) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext.subscribe(MonoNext.java:40) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:60) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSwitchIfEmpty.subscribe(MonoSwitchIfEmpty.java:44) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:60) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3080) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.drain(MonoIgnoreThen.java:167) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:56) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:150) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:67) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:76) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.innerNext(FluxConcatMap.java:271) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapInner.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:803) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:115) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:1626) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:156) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:1440) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onSubscribe(Operators.java:1314) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:90) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:54) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoMapFuseable.subscribe(MonoMapFuseable.java:59) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3080) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.drain(FluxConcatMap.java:418) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.onSubscribe(FluxConcatMap.java:210) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:128) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:61) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap.subscribe(FluxConcatMap.java:121) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext.subscribe(MonoNext.java:40) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSwitchIfEmpty.subscribe(MonoSwitchIfEmpty.java:44) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:60) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:60) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal.subscribe(MonoPeekTerminal.java:61) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:150) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1069) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipCoordinator.signal(MonoZip.java:241) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipInner.onNext(MonoZip.java:323) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:1626) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipInner.onSubscribe(MonoZip.java:312) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:54) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3080) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip.subscribe(MonoZip.java:128) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:60) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal.subscribe(MonoPeekTerminal.java:61) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekFuseable.subscribe(MonoPeekFuseable.java:74) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnErrorResume.subscribe(MonoOnErrorResume.java:44) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnErrorResume.subscribe(MonoOnErrorResume.java:44) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnErrorResume.subscribe(MonoOnErrorResume.java:44) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3080) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.drain(MonoIgnoreThen.java:167) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:56) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekFuseable.subscribe(MonoPeekFuseable.java:70) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal.subscribe(MonoPeekTerminal.java:61) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.ipc.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.applyHandler(ChannelOperations.java:380) ~[reactor-netty-0.7.5.RELEASE.jar:0.7.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.ipc.netty.http.server.HttpServerOperations.onHandlerStart(HttpServerOperations.java:397) ~[reactor-netty-0.7.5.RELEASE.jar:0.7.5.RELEASE]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163) ~[netty-common-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:404) ~[netty-common-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:463) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:886) ~[netty-common-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
```

What is the problem?

Comment: how are you accessing your endpoints? command line, browser tool, client application? What do your headers to and fro look like? Could there be a failure or error client side that causes it to request the /bad-request path?

Comment: I use `postman` I do request like in the question but with the header `application/json`

Comment: @Kylé it seems something is broken for sure. It tried to add simple class with `RestController` annotation and `GetMapping` and it still couldn't handle the request

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was doing `https` request instead of `http`. 
I realized that when I switched to `tomcat` and It returned me

```
Invalid character found in method name. HTTP method names must be tokens
```